# How can I verify my reconstructed gravity field of Ceres from spherical harmonics?

Tags: gravity, mathematics, ceres

Based on @DavidHammen's [very helpful answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27699/12102) I've made progress reconstructing the gravity field of Ceres from the Dawn radiometric data. The [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27689/12102) there contains further information, but suffice it to say here that I am using Version 2 of the data at https://sbn.psi.edu/pds/resource/dawn/dwncgravL2.html

Below is a Python script I've used to read the `JGDWN_CER18C_SHA.TAB` file and build the gravitational potential field. I am using SciPy's [`sph_harm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.sph_harm.html#scipy.special.sph_harm) which is normalized, and I am wondering how to be sure if this is *the same normalization* assumed by the NASA Planetary Data System's normalization in the phrase (within the `JGDWN_CER18C_SHA.LBL` file):

> Some details describing this model are:
>   - The spherical harmonic coefficients are fully normalized.

The SciPy documentation says (I've just copied the html from inspection of the webpage and it magically formats here too, yay!):

$$Y^m_n(\theta,\phi) = \sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{4\pi} \frac{(n-m)!}{(n+m)!}}
  e^{i m \theta} P^m_n(\cos(\phi))$$

I though I would compare to a published map, and I've found the image below which is topography and gravity, but these can not be compared for several reasons, including:

1. The published map is *gravitational* acceleration, not potential
2. it is a plot of [Bouguer anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouguer_anomaly) which is a little (too) complicated (for me) but roughly, if I understand correctly, it means that (among other things like projection, and other correction terms) it's the gravitational acceleration evaluated on the ellipsoidal surface, rather than at a fixed radius. It's also got (at least) the monopole term removed of course.

I understand that to get an acceleration *magnitude* map, you need to start with the gradient of the potential, but a full blown Bouguer anomaly can have other corrections way beyond what I need to understand right now. In fact what I'm after is [modeling Dawn's low periapsis orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27610/12102).

**Question:** Instead of comparing to this Bouguer anomaly plot, I'd like to compare my reconstruction of potential directly somehow. How can I do this? How can I check it?

"**extra credit:**" Do the PDS coefficients yield a reduced potential (energy per unit mass) with units of km^2/s^2 rather than m^2/s^2?

---

**below:** From Park et al. [A partially differentiated interior for (1) Ceres deduced from its gravity field and shape](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature18955) Nature volume 537, pages 515–517 (22 September 2016) https://doi.org/10.1038/nature18955

[image]

---

**below:** I've plotted U for n ≥ 5 and 4 because the low order terms overwhelm the r = Rref plot. Of course this is (probably one of several reasons) why people use Bouguer plots and evaluate on the ellipsoid.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import sph_harm

halfpi, pi, twopi = [f*np.pi for f in (0.5, 1, 2)]
degs, rads = 180/pi, pi/180

j = np.complex(0, 1)

fname = "JGDWN_CER18C_SHA.TAB"

with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

header_data = lines[0].split(',')

Rref, GM, GMerr = [float(x) for x in header_data[0:3]]
Order_0, Order_1, normalization_state = [int(x) for x in header_data[3:6]]

if normalization_state == 1:
    print "coefficients are normalized"
elif normalization_state == 0:
    print "coefficients are NOT normalized"
else:
    print "coefficients  normalization is unclear"

h_lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines[1:]]
indices = np.array([[int(x)   for x in line[0:2]] for line in h_lines])
coeffs  = np.array([[float(x) for x in line[2:4]] for line in h_lines])

Cstars = (np.array([1, +j]) * coeffs).sum(axis=1) # make coefficient complex

ph         = np.linspace(0,  pi,    180+1)[:-1]
th         = np.linspace(0,  twopi, 360+1)[:-1]
phi, theta = np.meshgrid(ph, th, indexing='ij')

# https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.sph_harm.html#scipy.special.sph_harm

harmonics = []

for (n, m), Cstar in zip(indices, Cstars):

    Y = sph_harm(m, n, theta, phi)

    harmonics.append((n, m, (Y * Cstar).real))  # 3-tuple of n, m, Y*C product

# evaluate gravitational potential
r = Rref

U_mono   = -GM/r

nmins = (5, 4)     # 5, 4, 3, 2

Us = []

for nmin in nmins:
    count = 0
    U = np.zeros_like(phi)
    for n, m, h in harmonics:
        if n >= nmin:
            U += h * (Rref/r)**n
            count += 1
    print nmin, count
    Us.append(U)

if True:
    plt.figure()
    for i, (nmin, U) in enumerate(zip(nmins, Us)):
        plt.subplot(len(Us), 1, i+1)
        plt.imshow(U, cmap='PuOr')
        plt.title('U_ceres(r=' + str(round(r, 1))  + 'km), nmin = ' + str(nmin), fontsize = 16)
        plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [How are the coefficients in the EGM96 model normalized?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/how-are-the-coefficients-in-the-egm96-model-normalized) Unfortunately, that question remains unanswered.

Comment: The scipy sph_harm package is not what you want. It uses the form of spherical harmonics favored in quantum physics. Geophysicists use a form that uses the real sine and cosine functions rather than the complex exponential, and the normalization is different.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks for your heads-up, this is really helpful! While making $Cstar = C + jS$ and then evaluating $ real(Y \ Cstar)$ effectively keeps them separate (though maybe I should have used a minus sign $Cstar = C - jS$ now that I think about it) the normalization is a real can of worms so I'm not surprised there could be more than one way to do it. Okay I will go hunting in geophysics papers. Maybe a "how to use" pdf associated with a WGS84 model will have it.

Comment: update: I've run across the following and investigating now; Physical Geodesy, 2nd (corrected) ed. Bernhard Hofmann-Wellenhof Helmut Moritz, SpringerWienNewYork, Section 1.10 Fully normalized spherical harmonics

Comment: Oh my lord... this has been a fun read man. Thank you for posting the code! As a developer this is awesome!!!

Comment: If you are trying to match gravity at the surface with spherical harmonics, good luck. It can be impossible since spherical harmonics diverge within the Brillouin sphere, that is why for landing operations polyhedron or mascons models are preferred. But maybe I have misunderstood the question. Anyway, if your final application is an orbiting body I would suggest to code manually a routine manually for the acceleration (there are analytic expression for the gradient) and check if the results matches the SciPy function (if any). Sorry, not a python user, but that is what I did in MATLAB

Comment: @Julio thanks for the speedy reply! Okay I will have a look at this again (it's been a while). Yes I want to calculate orbits but hopefully it will be outside some minimal sphere such that the harmonics are valid. I'll look again at what gravity data is available for Ceres...

Comment: @uhoh Not sure I can give a full answer, but in my experience normalised gravity coefficients usually means real harmonics, 4pi normalised. I understand you want to code things yourself, but perhaps check your calculations against the SHTOOLS library which is written for potential fields work in the Earth/planetary sciences. If you have access to ellipsoid and topography info this example notebook makes it straightforward to go down the Bouguer comparison route: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SHTOOLS/SHTOOLS/blob/master/examples/notebooks/gravity-and-magnetic-fields.ipynb

Comment: @WJB I'll have a look, thank you very much! Will a spacecraft orbiting Ceres work on Jupyter? :-)

Comment: @DavidHammen I've added a bounty...

Comment: @WJB ditto.....

Answer (score 5):

## Formulation

Brandon A. Jones wrote an excellent summary of the different formulations and methods to compute spherical harmonics in his 2010 PhD thesis available [here](https://scholar.colorado.edu/asen_gradetds/11/). Chapter 2 is especially of interest. You may also want to read Fantino & Casotto 2008 "Methods of harmonic synthesis for global geopotential models and their first-, second- and third-order gradients", which proposes a slightly simplified computation of the harmonics.

**Important:** the frame in which the harmonics is computed is a body fixed frame. In the case of Earth, you'll use the ECEF frame (cf. Chapter 2 of G. Xu and Y. Xu, GPS, DOI 10.1007/978-3-662-50367-6_2 -- which is open access -- for a through computation of that frame from an ECI frame using the IAU2000 framework). In the case of other bodies, and Ceres in particular, you'll need to create a body fixed frame. [This GMAT documentation](http://gmat.sourceforge.net/doc/R2016a/html/CoordinateSystem.html) may be of help.

## Normalization or not

I came across a similar problem myself a few weeks ago. In terms of the normalization, and at least in the cases of the Earth, Moon, and other kernels available on [PDS Geosciences Node](http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/), the SHADR files contain the normalized spherical harmonics. Similarly, the EGM2008 Tide Free model also contains normalized harmonics. This greatly simplifies the computation since you do not need to recompute harmonics with factorial math.

## Verification & validation

The verification step should be quite straight-forward, but the validation isn't. The process of verification, in my experience, consists in making sure that things are implemented correctly: one checks the coded math, and that all the block fit together. The validation step however, is more complicated. There, you want to make sure that the right thing was implemented, i.e. despite the math being right, is the correct frame used to compute the effect of the spherical harmonics on the orbiting vehicle.

As discussed above, both the SHADR and SHBDR files store the normalized coefficients. Hence, one method of validation, which I've opted for [my upcoming tool](https://github.com/ChristopherRabotin/nyx), consists in rigorously comparing results of the same scenario with another known validation tool. [In my case](https://github.com/ChristopherRabotin/nyx/blob/master/VALIDATION.md), I'm using NASA's GMAT and GMAT used [STK and others](https://github.com/ChristopherRabotin/nyx/blob/3426b3fee02c9b73c0e3f05e8d9aae0c31520660/tests/GMAT_scripts/GMAT_V&V_ProcessAndResults.pdf). Specifically in the case of GMAT however, I do not think it's possible to import SHADR files. So you'll need to convert it to the support COF file, or find another propagation tool which also allows you to turn on and off specific dynamics (in this case you'll want harmonics turned on to a given degree and order, but only Ceres as a point mass).

Comment: ChrisR to the rescue (again)! Okay I will give this a thorough read. Can you give me a tl;dr first though? Will I find some data points of gravitational potential at a few locations I can use as confirmation points, or is your answer that I will need to make room on my laptop, download, install under MacOS, and then learn a whole new program before I can get anything useful?

Comment: Right, sorry I didn't actually get to the core of your question. If you would like to verify your implementation, I think that comparing a Bouguer plot is a good start. For validation, you would need to look at specific numerical values. There are two methods for that. The first requires that you find values from a trusted source (like a paper), ie "with this given state, we get a gravity potential of X when using degree N and order M from file Z". The second possibility is finding a propagation result, or generating it from a source like GMAT (works on Windows, Linux and Mac).

Comment: @uhoh, you may also want to reach out to the planetary scientists at Open Planetary. They are very helpful and respond quite quickly on their public Slack chat system.

Comment: Okay well I thought I'd explained why comparing to a Bouguer plot would be a bad idea for me. I've never heard of Open Planetary, what is it?

Comment: Okay well I thought I'd explained why comparing to a Bouguer plot would be a bad idea for me. I've never heard of Open Planetary, what is it? Oh I see, it's a collection of head-shots of people trying to look smart, forward-thinking, and knowledgable. I think that websites which prominently display a dozen vanity [head-shots](http://openplanetary.co/community/) rather than science tend not to be very helpful, but okay I will take a look. Thanks for that suggestion!

Comment: @uhoh, have you checked out their Slack ( https://openplanetary.slack.com ). The folks there are usually responsive. Anyway, I just reread why you couldn't do the plot comparison, and it makes sense. You'd need to find a good reference for this. Moreover, yes, the spherical harmonics are with respect to a reference ellipsoid, so you need the flattening coefficient of that reference. Finally, you may want to check out NASA GEODYN, which is a Fortran code for precise geodesy extensively used even by today's PhD students (two friends use it every day).

Comment: "spherical harmonics are with respect to a reference ellipsoid" No, they aren't. However a Bouguer plot might show the strength of the *gravitational acceleration* on the ellipsoid. Is there any way to know of definitions in GEODYN for spherical harmonic coefficients are the same as those used in the Dawn/Ceres data?

Comment: You're right (and I was wrong): the harmonics are _not_ according to the reference ellipsoid, at least not for Earth harmonics. I asked a friend who knows geodesy much more than I do, and he recommended the following link for a good explanation of the Bouguer anomaly: http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2012/12110923-grail-results.html . I also do not think that GEODYN provides its own harmonics, but instead I think the user needs to specify them. Do take that last claim with extreme caution because I've never used GEODYN myself!

Comment: I was enquiring about GEODYN to see how it *uses spherical harmonic coefficients* to construct potential and acceleration fields, not to make them.

Comment: Just curious if you have any further thoughts on this. I'm going to add a bounty; feel free to add an additional answer if you have something more definitive, thanks!