# Calculating the Earth Geopotential effect

Tags: gravity, mathematics

I'm calculating the acceleration due to the harmonics in ECEF frame. Gravity potential in spherical harmonics is shown [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110023121.pdf) (I just removed "$1+$", as considering only harmonics effect).

$U_{har}=\frac{\mu}{r}[\sum_{i=2}^d\sum_{j=0}^o (\frac{R_{eq}}{r})^iP_{ij}(\sin\phi)(S_{ij}\sin{j\lambda}+C_{ij}\cos{j\lambda})]$,

where $d$ and $o$- degree and order, $\phi$ and $\lambda$- latitude and longitude respectively.

I compare the results with `GMAT`. For degree 2 and order 0 (J2) the error in propagation was 5m. But for degree/order=8 the error is 350km!

The steps:

1. In a loop $i\in[2,2]$, $j\in[0,0]$

   - Calculate the $P_i=\frac{d^{i+j}}{d\mu^{i+j}}(\mu^2-1)^i$
   - Calculate the Legendre polynom $P_{ij}=\frac{(1-\mu^2)^{\frac{j}{2}}}{i!*2^i}P_i$
   - Calculate the $sum+=P_{ij}(\frac{z}{r})*(C\cos(j*atan(\frac{y}{x}))+S\sin(j*atan(\frac{y}{x})))(\frac{R_{eq}}{r})^i$
2. Calculate the potential
   $U_{har}=\mu\frac{sum}{r}$
3. Calculate the $a_x$: $f=\frac{dU_{har}}{dx}$
4. Calculate the value in the point $f(r_x,r_y,r_z)$

As it seen, the latitude is $asin(\frac{z}{r})$ and longitude is $atan(\frac{y}{x})$

The coefficients (JGM-3):

```
2 0 -0.10826360229840e-02 0.0
2 1 -0.24140000522221e-09 0.15430999737844e-08
2 2 0.15745360427672e-05 -0.90386807301869e-06
```

---

I have written a code on Julia language, which builds the expression (depending on the degree and order).

```
using SatelliteToolbox
using SymEngine

path="C:/xampp/htdocs/sat_prop/";
JGM_coeff_file=string(path,"coeff.txt");

const date  = DatetoJD(2100,01,01,0,0,0)
const degree = 8

y = [-4617E+03, 1709E+03, -5040E+03]

const Req = 6378136.3
const GMe = 398600.4415E+9

function harmonics(dy,y,dU,date)
  dy= [
        dU[1](y[1],y[2],y[3]),
        dU[2](y[1],y[2],y[3]),
        dU[3](y[1],y[2],y[3])
      ]
end

function potential()

  @vars x y z myu

  CS=open(readdlm,JGM_coeff_file)

  longitude=atan( y/x );
  r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^(1/2)

  U_sum=0
  for i=2:degree
      for j=0:degree

          index=1+j; for ll=2:i-1 index+=ll+1; end

          P_i=(myu^2-1)^i
          for k=1:i+j P_i=diff(P_i,myu) end

          P_ij=(((1-myu^2)^(j/2))/(factorial(i)*2^i))*P_i

          if(P_ij!=0)
            U_sum+= P_ij(z/r)*(CS[index,3]*cos(j*longitude)+CS[index,4]*sin(j*longitude))*(Req/r)^i
          end
       end
  end

  U=GMe*(U_sum)/r

  return lambdify(expand(diff(U,x)),[x,y,z]),lambdify(expand(diff(U,y)),[x,y,z]),lambdify(expand(diff(U,z)),[x,y,z])
end


dU=potential();
dy=zero(y)
@time harmonics(dy,y,dU,date)
@time harmonics(dy,y,dU,date)
```

Comment: In what frame is the X, Y, and Z coordinates? They need to be in ECEF.

Comment: `+1` Great editing, this looks much better, very nice! I'll try to take a careful look today, thanks for taking the time to dig in with MathJax!

Comment: @Leeloo, okay, thanks for the edits. To be honest, I'm not sure how to answer this question sadly, as I've only used the Pines equations to compute the harmonics.

Comment: @Leeloo the equations are several pages long. A good reference is Chapter 2 of the PhD dissertation of Brandon A. Jones 2010. It's available freely on the University of Colorado website. The filename should be called "bajones2010" I think. He also mentions two other formulations which should speed up calculations (Fantino 2008), but they seemed significantly more complex to me. I've implemented Pines [here](https://github.com/ChristopherRabotin/nyx/blob/master/src/dynamics/gravity.rs), in Rust, as part of a toolkit I'm writing to automate most of the analysis I do, & with the fidelity of GMAT.

Comment: @Leeloo I'll take a look, that looks very promising! Possibly helpful here as well: [How can I verify my reconstructed gravity field of Ceres from spherical harmonics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27779/12102)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Julia language, but it seems to me that when you differentiate $U$ by $x$, you assume that $\mu$ and $\lambda$ stay constant as $x$ changes, which is wrong. You say that you have already tried to replace latitude with $\text{asin}(\frac{z}{r})$, longitude with $\text{atan}(\frac{y}{x})$; could you please show the program with these changes?

Comment: @Litho Updated.

Comment: Shouldn't `myu` be calculated as `z/r` in the `potential` function?

Comment: @Litho No, there is the derivative by `myu`. But then it replaced as `z/r`.
I suppose, the problem is in that, the longitude should be `atan2(y,x)`

Comment: Well, as I said, I'm not familiar with Julia, but it seems to me that this approach implies that `myu` doesn't depend on `x`, `y` and `z`. But it does, so the derivatives are wrong.

Comment: @Litho It's not about the language: in the Legendre polynom you calculate the derivative by `myu`. But then, when you calculate the derivative of `U`, the `myu` is replaced by `z/r`

Comment: Oh, I see now. You use `P_ij(z/r)` when calculating `U_sum`. I didn't notice it before.

Comment: Can you show us the first few lines of your coefficients file?

Comment: @cms Added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Be careful with arc tangent

I am unfamiliar with Julia, but in most languages $\arctan(y/x)$ returns a value between $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. It does this because it doesn't know if $y$ or $x$ is positive or negative. So when you calculate longitude as:

$$ \lambda = \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) = \arctan(\frac{4617\times10^3}{-1709\times 10^3}) = -69.7^\circ$$

That is in the 4th quadrant, which is $180^\circ$ off from where the longitude actually is (the 2nd quadrant when $y$ is positive and $x$ is negative). This doesn't matter for the $j=0$ terms like J2, but it inverts the tesseral terms, since $\sin( \theta + 180 ) = - \sin \theta$ and $\cos( \theta + 180) = -\cos ( \theta )$. That would explain the discrepancy in agreement when adding more terms.

#### Use a arctan2

Most languages have a special function (usually called "atan2(x,y)" or some variant) that takes two parameters: an x and y parameter. If you don't have one, you will have to use some if statements to consider which quadrant the longitude is actually in.

Comment: You're absolutely right. However, there're some troubles with atan2 in Julia, so I used `longitude=atan(y/x)+pi*sign(y)*(1-sign(x))/2`. Is it OK? Assumed, that x and y are never 0.